# how to multiply vector 'double' to vector 'int32' matlab

Tags: matlab, double, int32

I have 1X6 double vector  A (where values change during the run):

```
 0.0155    0.1566    0.0454    0.0146    0.3967    0.1879
```

I have another 1x6 int32 vector B (where values also change during the run):

```
120          14          42        2874           7  2147483647
```

I need to multiply these two and return C=A.*B:

```
1.86       2.1924         1.9068   ...              403512177.2713
```

any ideas on how to do it? I have been looking for solution for the past 2 hours and couldnt find anything helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just use `C = A.*double(B)`?

Comment: yes it works, i just tried the same

Comment: @LuisMendo No it doesnt work for me. I get C = 
   1.0e+08 *

   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -3.5791

Comment: @mil It does work. That's the _correct_ answer. Type `format long` and you'll see

Comment: Or use `sprintf` to format the result: for example, `sprintf('%15.5f', A.*double(B))`

Comment: @LuisMendo. Thanks you so much! I had the correct answer but couldnt understand it. Format long and sprintf helped a lot!